# Why does camel Kafka wait for sometime after a consumer rebalance

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, kafka-consumer-api

Going through the camel kafka consumer code it can be seen that in KafkaFetchRecords there is the below code:

```
if (!first) {
       // skip one poll timeout before trying again
       long delay = endpoint.getConfiguration().getPollTimeoutMs();
       log.info("Reconnecting {} to topic {} after {} ms", threadId, topicName, delay);
       try {
            Thread.sleep(delay);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
            }
```

This delay has a default value of 5 seconds. I am trying to understand why this is required and also whether there will be any issue if I reduce this to 1 second. 5 seconds seems to be a lot of time for which as far as I understand, it will be a complete stop for any processing.

Referece file: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/kafka/KafkaConsumer.java

Line No: 198